# Which Country Has All Wifi Channels Open?

Tags: wireless, atheros

As in US , we can't use anything above 11, which country has all channels available for use on Wifi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Countries apply their own regulations to both the allowable channels,
>   allowed users and maximum power levels within these frequency ranges.
>   Consult your local authorities as these regulations may be out of date
>   as they are subject to change at any time. Most of the world will
>   allow the first thirteen channels in the spectrum.

To Answer you question its ***Japan***.  [Check This out !](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)

Source: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/wireless/wi-fi/80211-channels-number-frequencies-bandwidth.php)